# GWT and animated gif: how to display individual frames?

Tags: gwt

Using GWT, is it possible to use an animated gif and display only a specific frame from it? For example, to display frame 4 and then later on display frame 5. Do we have control over the individual frames of an animated gif in GWT?

Comment: Are you asking in terms of what Java can do or what the compiled GWT application will be able to do on the client? JavaScript, in and of itself, has **zero** control over the animation of gifs. However, you might be able to tear apart a GIF on the server side and serve back the individual frames.

Comment: I was asking in terms of what can be done on browser side with GWT. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible in GWT, and it's not possible in JavaScript either.

As Cory suggested, you can split a GIF into individual frames on a server side, and then serve individual images based on browser events.